# Mysterious "undefined reference" linker errors

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

for a university project I'm doing a port of a handtracking algorithm for Android. The alg. mainly uses OpenCV functions. Honestly I don't really understand what the alg. does but this is not my problem.
So for porting the alg. I added every file from a working windows visual studio project to my android project fixing some compiler warnings and errors here and there. Mostly with success...
Unfortunaly there is one file that worries me for many many hours.
Compiling this file throws following errors:

```
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvFindChessBoardCornerGuesses':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvFindChessBoardCornerGuesses+0x18): undefined reference to `cvFindChessboardCorners'
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvHoughLines':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvHoughLines+0x46): undefined reference to `cvHoughLines2'
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvHoughLinesSDiv':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvHoughLinesSDiv+0x54): undefined reference to `cvHoughLines2'
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvHoughLinesP':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvHoughLinesP+0x52): undefined reference to `cvHoughLines2'
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvCalcEMD':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvCalcEMD+0x44): undefined reference to `cvCalcEMD2'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The funny thing about that is that the only line causing this error is

```
nPointsConnected ++;
```

Commenting this line or decrementing nPointsConnected or setting a value like nPointsConnected=1 makes the linker error disappear.

There are other files in the project including the same OpenCV headers compiling fine.
Could anybody please explain this to me? 
please...

EDIT
This is the surround code:

```
 if ( minK > FINGERTIP_ANGLE_THRESHOLD && minDir > 0 )
    {
        nPointsGap = 0;
        if ( nPointsConnected == 0 )
            {
                startIndex = i;
            }

        nPointsConnected ++;
        if ( minAngle < minK )
        {
            minAngle = minK;
            minPointIndex = i;
        }
        fConnected = true;
        mediumIndex += ( minK * i );
        meanPointX += ( minK * contour[i].x );
        meanPointY += ( minK * contour[i].y );
        sumAngle += minK;
        if ( fScreenshot )
        {
            cvCircle( pScreenshot_curvature, cvPoint(contour[i].x*2, contour[i].y*2),
                4, CV_RGB(255,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
            cvCircle( pScreenshot_ellipse, cvPoint(contour[i].x*2, contour[i].y*2),
                4, CV_RGB(255,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are not using the right version of open CV. Try this question with a C+°+ tag..

Comment: I do not think so because this project is based on a working OpenCV sample project.

Comment: Can you post your code little bit more around the problematic line?

Comment: if that nPointsConnected is some object it could have a complicated operator++ override which could use all these library functions..

Comment: no it is of type int. Forgot to mention it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks as if you ended up pulling in the `compat.o` object file from `-lopencv_legacy` and as if this file delegates to another implementation. That is, you probably need to specify `-lopencv` after `-lopencv_legacy`.

I don't know anything about Android or OpenCV but this is how the error messages look like. Your description of what caused the problem look a bit weird unless `nPointsConnected` is some class type. In this case it might be that the increment operator is only implemented in the compatibility library while other operations are available in the "real" implementation. Using `nm` on your object file you could find what additional symbol(s) your changed caused to be undefined and then see in which library they are defined.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your suggestions. nPointsDisconnected is a simple integer.

Comment: On what file will nm be applied?

Comment: It works with binaries: object files (.o), libraries (.a), shared libraries (.so), and executables. I writes symbol information. I typically use it like "nm -po foo.o | less". "U" characters indicate undefined symbols, other symbols are definitions of different kind. Getting the symbols before and after the change should indicate which symbols are newly undefined. Sending these to c++filt should give an indication on how the C++ looked like (typically without the [return] type.

Comment: Thanks Dietmar. Your first answer was quite useful but I couldn't really interprete it for me :-/

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify,
as some people here assumed the problem was not the incremented integer causing this error. 
Furthermore it was a method call within an if condition

```
(nPointsConnected > SOMEVALUE)
```

What I had to do was changing the order of the OpenCV modules in the OpenCV makefile
from

```
OPENCV_MODULES := contrib calib3d objdetect features2d video imgproc highgui ml legacy flann core ts
```

to

```
OPENCV_MODULES := contrib legacy objdetect calib3d features2d video highgui imgproc ml flann core
```

where the legacy module was the one to be replaced. (Many thanks to the guy from the android-opencv mailing list who pointed this out)